# Reading and writing files and resources

Tags: java, io

Doing IO in Java is a big pain. It got better with Guava and Java 7 and now about everything is there, but I never know exactly where.

Most of the time I need to slurp a file. Nearly as often I need to write a file, while making sure, I don't end up with some garbage in case of an IO error (atomicity). Leaving `.tmp` files around in such a case is intended. Overwriting (and then deleting) a `xxx.tmp` when `xxx` gets written is a non-issue for me.

Sometimes the location is given like `clazz.getResource(name)`. Sometimes, this resource is a file (when working in an IDE with sources and class files; I sometimes generate some data files in the source tree), sometimes it's not. Reading must work in both cases, writing only in the first.

The encoding is **UTF-8** by default, but can be changed. Concerning platform default encoding, I don't give a damn, as the the files must be portable by simply binary copying them from one system to another. It's all rather hacky, but it does exactly what I want.

*The **imports** are omitted for brevity and can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/cr/MyIoResource.java). Feel free to ignore **one-liners** containing conditions, as I'm not gonna change this.*

<sup>I'll probably rewrite it to be Android-compatible, so **no try with resources** (there'll be a problem with `java.nio.file`, but on Linux files moves are atomic, so it's not needed; the challenge will be to get atomicity on both Windows with Java 7+ and Android with Java 6).</sup>

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE) public class MyIoResource {
    public MyIoResource(File file) {
        this(UTF8, checkNotNull(file), null, null);
    }

    public MyIoResource(Class<?> clazz, String name) {
        this(UTF8, null, checkNotNull(clazz), checkNotNull(name));
    }

    public MyIoResource asAnsi() {
        return withCharset(ANSI);
    }

    public byte[] readBytes() throws IOException {
        if (file!=null) return Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        final URL url = newUrl(clazz, name);
        final InputStream in = url.openStream();
        try {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ByteStreams.copy(in, result);
            return result.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    public String readString() throws IOException {
        return new String(readBytes(), charset);
    }

    public void writeAtomic(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        checkNotNull(data);
        final File file = this.file!=null ? this.file : newFile();
        final File tmpFile = new File(file.getParent(), file.getName() + ".tmp");
        final StandardCopyOption[] options = {StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING};
        Files.write(tmpFile.toPath(), data);
        Files.move(tmpFile.toPath(), file.toPath(), options);
    }

    public void writeAtomic(String data) throws IOException {
        writeAtomic(data.getBytes(charset));
    }

    public void writeAtomic(CharSequence data) throws IOException {
        writeAtomic(data.toString());
    }

    public void writeAtomic(Iterable<String> data) throws IOException {
        if (Iterables.isEmpty(data)) {
            writeAtomic(new byte[0]);
        } else {
            writeAtomic(Joiner.on('\n').appendTo(new StringBuilder(), data).append('\n'));
        }
    }

    private File newFile() throws IOException {
        final URL dirUrl = newUrl(clazz, ".");
        final URL url = new URL(dirUrl, name);
        try {
            return new File(url.toURI());
        } catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new IOException(e); // Don't pollute everything with URISyntaxException.
        }
    }

    private static URL newUrl(Class<?> clazz, String name) throws NoSuchFileException {
        final URL url = clazz.getResource(name);
        if (url!=null) return url;
        throw new NoSuchFileException("No such resource: " + clazz.getName() + " " + name);
    }

    private static final Charset UTF8 = Charsets.UTF_8;
    private static final Charset ANSI = Charsets.ISO_8859_1;

    @Wither private final Charset charset;
    private final File file;
    private final Class<?> clazz;
    private final String name;
}
```

Comment: Android isn't supposed to support some Java 7 features like Auto-closeable ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480090/does-android-support-jdk-6-or-7 (This would really simplify some of your problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sometimes the location is given like `clazz.getResource(name)`.
>   Sometimes, this resource is a file (when working in an IDE with
>   sources and class files; I sometimes generate some data files in the
>   source tree), sometimes it's not. Reading must work in both cases,
>   writing only in the first.

It sounds like this one class should really be two classes.
Another indicator of that is when you have constructors used like this:

```
    this(charset, file, null, null);
    this(charset, null, clazz, name);
```

That's really two implementations masquerading as one class.

How about splitting to smaller pieces:

- `IoResource`: common interface that file-based and location-based resources can implement
- `AbstractIoResource`: skeletal implementation of common logic
- `FileIoResource`: file-based implementation, with appropriate constructor
- `ClassPathIoResource`: location-based implementation, with appropriate constructor, and write operations throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`

If you don't want to force clients to know the right class names for the appropriate types,
you can provide factory methods in one common class.
For inspiration, think of `Collections` and its various methods,
such as `Collections.synchronizedList` and `Collections.unmodifiableList`:
the actual implementation types are not visible to clients.
If you go with this approach, then the `FileIoResource` and `ClassPathIoResource` implementation can be even private.

Comment: +1 I was so happy that I could unify the access that I didn't think about split implementations. I guess, I'll create the hierarchy (but probably without the interface as I can easily add it later if ever needed). The `UOE` is a good idea as well.